# private menu with flexible size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a site that uses bootstrap classes. I've designed a menu that slides out of screen right, covering the contents. I want the menu to automatically be the height of the screen, and be col-xs-2. This is what I tried, but the menu opens to cover the whole page, and, of course, the height is 300px instead of being the height of the screen:

**HTML**

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-10">
        <a id="menuTrigger" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-2">
        <div id="myMenu">
           <div id="item1" class="submenu">Item 1</div>
           <div id="item2" class="submenu">Item 2</div>
           <div id="item3" class="submenu">Item 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
mnuOut=false;

$('#menuTrigger').click(function(){
     if (mnuOut){ 
         $('#myMenu').animate({
            right: '-100%'
         },800);
         mnuOut = false;
     }else{
     $('#myMenu').animate({
         right: 0
     },800);
     mnuOut = true;
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
#myMenu  { position:fixed; 
           top:20px; 
           right:-100%; 
           width:100%; 
           height:300px; 
           background:palegreen;}
.submenu{width:100%;height:20px;padding:20px 5px;border:1px solid green;}
#menuTrigger:hover{cursor:pointer;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried mmenu?  http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

that's what i used.  note that browser's on phones (chrome in particular) won't do the sub-menu's properly for some reason (could have been updated)